# Ways to access an object that triggered a breakpoint?

Tags: javascript

In chrome console, I have set some breakpoints in code of the sources. Those are set in a class for which an instance of this class was instantiated at loadtime. :

```
var SearcherBlock = function(n) {
    function t() {
        n.apply(this, arguments);
        this.CurrentData = null;
        this.onInput = null;
        this.SearchInput = document.getElementById(this.BlockUniqueID + "_SearchInput");
        this.SearchResults = document.getElementById(this.BlockUniqueID + "_Search_Results");
        this.SearchResultsTitle = document.getElementById(this.BlockUniqueID + "_ResultsTitle");
        this.onDocumentClick = this.onDocumentClickHandler.bind(this);
        this.MinSearchStringLength = SearchController.getMinSearchStringLength(this.Configuration.LanguagesFor2SymbolSearch)
    }
   var i = {
        destroyed: !0
    };
    return $.extend(t.prototype, n.prototype),
    t.prototype.activate = function() {
        n.prototype.activate.call(this);
        this.onInput = this.textChange.bind(this);
        this.SearchInput && this.SearchInput.addEventListener("input", this.onInput, !1);
        this.tooltipsInit()
    }
   t.prototype.textChange = function(n) {
       var t = n.srcElement || n.target;
       if (this.SearchResultsTitle.innerHTML) {
          ... }
   }
}
```

So now when I am at a breakpoint in this class whose instance I would like to achieve is triggered in this class. I would like to figure out a way to access this instance, like `window.something.something` - how can I do this if possible?

The reason is that when I call the function `hasText()` by `window.hasText()`, it complains because all properties of the `this` that is being used in the function are undefined. Therefore, I would like to have a way of accessing the instantiated object.

Comment: Breakpoints are native code (in your case Chrome) so I don't think you can do anything with them in your code IIRC.

Comment: On the right side, where the Variables and Scopes are listed: right click on the variable you want, then "Store as global variable"